# Where is the animation demo for Material Design Lite?

Tags: material-design-lite

Following the instructions of Material Design Lite's README, I have successfully build and served the local version of MDL website. I found that folder `material-design-lite\dist\` was served.

What I curious about is, there is a folder called `animation`, and its path is `material-design-lite\dist\components\animation`. However, I can't seem to navigate to there by clicking here and there on MDL website. I can access through https://getmdl.io/components/animation/demo.html though.

Anyone have insight on this? Is there any place or thing that I overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation is not a component on its own per-say but just a [quick set of classes](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/mdl-1.x/src/animation/_animation.scss) to get our transitions in place if you need them.

There aren't any documents on this since explaining how and why it should be used gets into murky territory for documentation authors trying to explain it concisely.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. So the classes are actually reflecting this documentation [Duration and easing](https://www.google.com/design/spec/motion/duration-easing.html#duration-easing-natural-easing-curves), minus the `Sharp curve`, is that correct?

Comment: The classes are our best setup for Material Animations on the web. As far as where exactly they came from, I do not know myself since I didn't build them. I'd assume they were as specific to the specification as they could get.